# Sequential chapter numbering by text

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, context, counters

The structure of my document consists of parts and chapters. When a new part is added a chapter counter is reset and a chapter numbering starts from 1 again.

```
\setuphead[part]
[
    page=no,
    deepnumbercommand=\convertnumber{Romannumerals},
    placehead=yes
]

\definenumber[chapter][way=bytext]

\setuphead[chapter]
[
    page=no,
    sectionsegments=2,
    alternative=middle    
]


\starttext

    \startpart[title=First part]

        \startchapter[title=First chapter]
        \stopchapter

        \startchapter[title=Second chapter]
        \stopchapter

    \stoppart

    \startpart[title=Second part]

        \startchapter[title=Third chapter should have the number 3]
        \stopchapter

    \stoppart

\stoptext
```

I need to get a sequential chapter numbering, independent of parts.
How can I do it?

Comment: Add to your preamble `\counterwithout{chapter}{part}`.

Comment: @Bernard The format used isn’t LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg: for my excuse, this wasn't obvious  from the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for (see [contextgarden](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineresetset))

```
\defineresetset[default][1,0][1]% reset part but not chapter
```